# Creating a standalone project with image recognition

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I can't seem to find a way to create a standalone package for image recognition. I have a project I'm writing in python, and I found a way to do what I need using `OpenCV`, but I can't find a way to import the library into my project unless it is installed at the system level on Ubuntu. In other words, I can't seem to plop the `build` folder into my project after building the `OpenCV` library. And I can't find the equivalent of `cv2.matchTemplate()` in `PIL` or `Pillow`. So really there are two questions here.

1) How can I attach the `build` folder to my project, in order to avoid installing the `OpenCV` at the system level.

2) Is there an equivalent of `cv2.matchTemplate()` in `PIL` or `Pillow` that I can't seem to find?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

- Download OpenCV
- Use CMake to tell it to compile statically and to tell it to compile the Python module
- Compile, and install into a directory you want.
- Find in that directory the file under a directory called python, called cv2.so
- Distribute that file with your Python code.

Now that I told you how to do it, let me tell you why your approach isn't a very good idea:

- If the version of Python changes, you need to recompile (the so file) and redistribute your entire application
- If the version of OpenCV changes you will need to recompile (the so file) and redistribute your entire application
- You don't control what version of Python your users have
- There can be important subtleties in version of libjpg, libtiff, zlib and others that could prevent your application from working, all outside your control.
- You are converting a multi-platform application into a platform specific solution.

Comment: Awesome answer, I'd give +5 if I could. Can I pay you to explain the second bit to people who are supposedly smarter than me please?